# Laravel get value from html

Tags: php, html, laravel

When i use statement below to choose a value belongs to Integer:

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" name="'svdk_khoa" id="'svdk_khoa" value="{{old('svdk_khoa')}}">
```

When it displays, i can choose a value. After that, it returns null in my methods from Controller as:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
     $sinhviendk->svdk_khoa=$request->svdk_khoa;
    ...
    }
```

How can i get real value? please

Comment: you have `name="'svdk_khoa"` isn't there a ' extra ?

Comment: oh sorry that is only "svdk_khoa"

Comment: Simply via `$request['svdk_khoa'];`.

Comment: Hi @ThanhToàn In controller you can  use this line  $request->svdk_khoa

Comment: @MayurPanchal that will not work. Look at the `name=` property in the OP's HTML.

Comment: i get it. it's my fault from syntax

Answer (score 0):

Change from `name="'svdk_khoa"` to `name="svdk_khoa"`

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="svdk_khoa" id="svdk_khoa" value="{{old('svdk_khoa')}}">
```